# Facebook Unnamed app issue

Tags: facebook, fbml, fbjs

I've created a facebook app.

When i try to send friend request,the app name is showing "Unnamed app" & the rquest is connecting to faceook homepage only
I tried with different app ids. but nothing worked.
Please Help me to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check these solutions http://ca.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100126190431AAJkPoW and http://www.snopes.com/computer/internet/unnamed.asp

Answer (score 2):

Go to the [Dev App](http://developers.facebook.com/apps) and ensure that the app is named correctly.